# Not able to install keras

Tags: python, keras

I was trying to install keras but its not installing

I have used `pip install keras` command for installation

Below error occured I have properly installed python:

```
Building wheel for dm-tree (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for dm-tree (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [80 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\tree
      copying tree\sequence.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\tree
      copying tree\tree_benchmark.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\tree
      copying tree\tree_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\tree
      copying tree\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\tree
      running build_ext
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 77, in _check_build_environment
        File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 408, in check_call
          retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 389, in call
          with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
          self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
        File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1538, in _execute_child
          hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

  The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\ROHIT\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
      main()
    File "C:\Users\ROHIT\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\ROHIT\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 251, in build_wheel
      return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\ROHIT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-st9vh7mn\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 404, in build_wheel
      return self._build_with_temp_dir(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\ROHIT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-st9vh7mn\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 389, in _build_with_temp_dir
      self.run_setup()
    File "C:\Users\ROHIT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-st9vh7mn\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 480, in run_setup
      super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend, self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
    File "C:\Users\ROHIT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-st9vh7mn\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
      exec(code, locals())
    File "<string>", line 124, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\ROHIT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-st9vh7mn\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 103, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\ROHIT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-st9vh7mn\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 185, in setup
      return run_commands(dist)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\ROHIT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-st9vh7mn\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 201, in run_commands
      dist.run_commands()
    File "C:\Users\ROHIT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-st9vh7mn\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "C:\Users\ROHIT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-st9vh7mn\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 963, in run_command
      super().run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\ROHIT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-st9vh7mn\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\ROHIT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-st9vh7mn\overlay\Lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 368, in run
      self.run_command("build")
    File "C:\Users\ROHIT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-st9vh7mn\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\ROHIT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-st9vh7mn\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 963, in run_command
      super().run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\ROHIT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-st9vh7mn\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\ROHIT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-st9vh7mn\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build.py", line 131, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "C:\Users\ROHIT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-st9vh7mn\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\ROHIT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-st9vh7mn\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 963, in run_command
      super().run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\ROHIT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-st9vh7mn\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "<string>", line 70, in run
    File "<string>", line 80, in _check_build_environment
  RuntimeError: CMake must be installed to build the following extensions: _tree
  [end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for dm-tree
Failed to build dm-tree
ERROR: Could not build wheels for dm-tree, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

i try installing dm-tree after cmake but its also not working

Answer (score 0):

Just install the old version of Python.

earlier I have installed python 3.12.1 version, here I'm unable to install keras
so I installed the older version 3.11.1 version and all set everything works fine here.